# loop returning the same value

Tags: javascript

I need to replace a template array with values from another array and push it to the final result.
This is what I have tried, the problem is that I get the same value when I loop.

```
  var pickups = [
    { address: "Lusaka, Zambia", distance: 22 },
    { address: "Ndola, Zambia", distance: 44 }
  ];

  var template = [{ lable: "distance", data: 0 }];

  var final_templates = [];

  var pickup_temp = template;

  for (var i = 0; i < pickups.length; i++) {
    for (var m = 0; m < template.length; m++) {
      if (pickup_temp[m].lable == "distance") {
        pickup_temp[m].data = pickups[i].distance;
      }
    }
    final_templates.push(pickup_temp);
  }

  console.log(final_templates);
```

Expected Result:

```
[[{lable: "distance", data: 22}],[{lable: "distance", data: 44}]]
```

Actual Result (same distance value):

```
[[{lable: "distance", data: 44}],[{lable: "distance", data: 44}]]
```

Comment: `pickup_temp` is the same object every time you `pickup_temp[m].data = $scope.pickups[i].distance;` - you'll need a new pickup_temp for each iteration

Comment: it's hard to know what you really want to get harry.

Comment: I need to create a new template array from the pickups data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simpler if the code avoids `for` loops and just uses [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
  var pickups = [
    { address: "Lusaka, Zambia", distance: 22 },
    { address: "Ndola, Zambia", distance: 44 }
  ];

  var template = [{ lable: "distance", data: 0 }];

  var final = pickups.map(pick => (
      template.map( item => (
          { label: item.lable, data: pick[item.lable] }
      ))
  ));

  console.log(JSON.stringify(final));
```